# C++ Cascading Stream Insertion (HW Help)

Tags: c++, stream, filestream

I found this potential solution in previous stack question. My problem is that it's not outputting to the file.

The program terminates without errors and actually does what it's supposed to do as I have verified this with a `cout`.

The program takes in a 7-digit phone number. Then writes to a file all possible words that can be made with those 7 digits, respecting the letter-number association on a standard telephone.

Program uses two functions: `main` and `wordGenerator` and includes `iostream, fstream, & cstdlib`

`main` :

```
int main()
{
 int phoneNumber[ 7 ] = { 0 }; // holds phone number

 // prompt user to enter phone number
 cout << "Enter a phone number (digits 2 through 9) " << "in the form: xxx-xxxx\n";

 // loop 8 times: 7 digits plus hyphen;
 // hyphen is not placed in phoneNumber
 for ( int u = 0, v = 0; u < 8; u++ )
     {
         int i = cin.get();

         // test if i is between 0 and 9
         if ( i >= '0' && i <= '9' )
             phoneNumber[ v++ ] = i - '0';
         } // end for

 wordGenerator( phoneNumber ); // form words from phone number
} // end main
```

`wordGenerator` :

```
void wordGenerator( const int * const n )
{
cout << "Some Word Forming Magic is going on!" << endl;

// set output stream and open output file
ofstream outFile("phone.dat");

// letters corresponding to each number
const char * phoneLetters[] = {"___", "___", "ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO", "PRS", "TUV", "WXY"};

// terminate if file could not be opened
if ( !outFile )
{
    cerr << "File could not be opened! Program Terminating..." << endl;
    exit(1);
}

 int count = 0; // number of words found

 // output all possible combinations
 for ( int i1 = 0; i1 <= 2; i1++ )
     {
         for ( int i2 = 0; i2 <= 2; i2++ )
             {
                 for ( int i3 = 0; i3 <= 2; i3++ )
                     {
                         for ( int i4 = 0; i4 <= 2; i4++ )
                             {
                                 for ( int i5 = 0; i5 <= 2; i5++ )
                                     {
                                         for ( int i6 = 0; i6 <= 2; i6++ )
                                             {
                                                 for ( int i7 = 0; i7 <= 2; i7++ )
                                                     {
/* I think the next 8 lines is what's not working! */
/* Write a series of cascaded stream insertion operations 
to output a set of seven letters to outFile, followed by a space */

outFile
<< phoneLetters[n[0]][i1]
<< phoneLetters[n[1]][i2]
<< phoneLetters[n[2]][i3]
<< phoneLetters[n[3]][i4]
<< phoneLetters[n[4]][i5]
<< phoneLetters[n[5]][i6]
<< phoneLetters[n[6]][i7]
<< " ";

                                                         if ( ++count % 9 == 0 ) // form rows
                                                             outFile << '\n';
                                                         }
                                                 }
                                         }
                                 }
                         }
                 }
         }

//alert user that wordGenerator has completed
cout << "Writing to file..." << endl;

// output phone number
outFile << "\nPhone number is ";

for ( int i = 0; i < 7; i++ )
    {
        if ( i == 3 )
            outFile << '-';

        outFile << n[ i ];

    } // end for


//print results to screen
cout << count / 9 << " words were created from" << endl;

//close output file
outFile.close();

} // end function wordGenerator
```

Program runs fine. No errors, except nothing is written to the output file `phone.dat`

Comment: I know the nested for loops are hideous. This is a template I must obey as it's an assignment. Sorry if that makes this more difficult.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? (It's fine if it is, but I just want to know so it can be tagged properly, if necessary).

Comment: yes it's homework, should I tag it as such? I was unaware. My apologies.

Comment: Try instead of outputting to a file, try outputting to cout and see if it prints anything. Also try to use a debugger if you can.

Comment: Which operation system do you use? If you use *nix, make sure that you can actually write to the file. Your program runs fine on Win7 x64.

Comment: @Drise: He already did: *"The program terminates without errors and actually does what it's supposed to do as I have verified this with a `cout`."*

Comment: I'm using XCode on a mac. Program runs as a command line tool.

Comment: @Zeta Fair enough. I didn't catch that.

Comment: @frankV: Mac is a [unix-like system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-like). Try `chmod +w phone.dat` before running your program. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod

Comment: @frankV Not a problem. It just makes categorisation easier in the future.

Comment: @Zeta: tried that, compiled and ran the .cpp file in terminal using `make filename`. Still nothing. Maybe I did something wrong?

Comment: Is the file created but empty or not created at all?

Comment: BTW, shouldn't you use '\r' instead of '\n' on MAC to force newline? I am also not sure if ofstream opens by default in text or binary mode. Both things may make a difference.

Comment: @Tomek file is already created and empty.

Comment: Have you tried removing the empty `phone.dat` file before running the program again?

Comment: @user315052 yes.I changed the `ofstream` to `ios::out` so it'll create a new one. Currently it is not doing that either. Working through it, this may be the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm so embarrassed to write this. It turns out that the code **has been working all along**. The output file is saved into `/Users/userName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` and after running the program that directory disappears.

So in order to combat this you must go to XCode's Preferences, click on "Locations" and change the setting for "Derived Data" from "default" to "relative".

I hope this helps someone else in the future...